# How to turn a set of flat trees into a single tree with multiple leaves?

Tags: postgresql, json, cte, recursive, tree

We have [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9b4914d865c3c1182ed488ae59eb3df5) beautiful Postgres tree generator. Yet it kind of produces cuts of a tree not a whole tree all at once:

```json
item_id jsonb_pretty
1   {
    "title": "PARENT",
    "item_id": 1,
    "children": {
        "title": "LEVEL 2",
        "item_id": 2,
        "children": {
            "title": "LEVEL 3.2",
            "item_id": 6
        }
    }
}
1   {
    "title": "PARENT",
    "item_id": 1,
    "children": {
        "title": "LEVEL 2",
        "item_id": 2,
        "children": {
            "title": "LEVEL 3.1",
            "item_id": 3,
            "children": {
                "title": "LEVEL 4.1",
                "item_id": 4
            }
        }
    }
}
1   {
    "title": "PARENT",
    "item_id": 1,
    "children": {
        "title": "LEVEL 2",
        "item_id": 2,
        "children": {
            "title": "LEVEL 3.1",
            "item_id": 3,
            "children": {
                "title": "LEVEL 4.2",
                "item_id": 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get a single tree object out from it with an array like this:

```json
1   {
    "title": "PARENT",
    "item_id": 1,
    "children": [{
        "title": "LEVEL 2",
        "item_id": 2,
        "children": [{
            "title": "LEVEL 3.2",
            "item_id": 6
        },
        {
            "title": "LEVEL 3.1",
            "item_id": 3,
            "children": [{
                "title": "LEVEL 4.1",
                "item_id": 4
            },
            {
                "title": "LEVEL 4.2",
                "item_id": 5
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Here is the generator:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  item_id     serial PRIMARY KEY,
  title text
);
CREATE TABLE joins (
  id          serial PRIMARY KEY,
  item_id     int,
  child_id    int
);
INSERT INTO items (item_id,title) VALUES
  (1,'PARENT'),
  (2,'LEVEL 2'),
  (3,'LEVEL 3.1'),
  (4,'LEVEL 4.1'),
  (5,'LEVEL 4.2'),
  (6,'LEVEL 3.2');
INSERT INTO joins (item_id, child_id) VALUES
  (1,2),
  (2,3),
  (3,4),
  (3,5),
  (2,6);

WITH RECURSIVE t(item_id, json, level) AS (
        SELECT item_id, to_jsonb(items), 1
        FROM items
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 2
                FROM joins
                WHERE items.item_id = joins.item_id
        )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT parent.item_id, to_jsonb(parent) || jsonb_build_object( 'children', t.json ),
               level + 1
        FROM t
        JOIN joins AS j
                ON t.item_id = j.child_id
        JOIN items AS parent
                ON j.item_id = parent.item_id
        WHERE level < 7
)
SELECT item_id, jsonb_pretty(json)
FROM t
WHERE item_id = 1;
```

How would I change such a generator to produce one single tree in Postgres 13+?

Comment: Generally, I understand that one could just call something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66059820/merge-two-json-object-in-python/66059974#66059974 in PL/Python... yet wonder if there are simpler more Postgres SQL native approaches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) (rCTE) is the right tool to follow the path and identify all nodes of a tree.
But it **does not allow aggregation** in the recursive term. There is an elegant alternative:

### Recursive function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_item_tree(_item_id int, _level int = 7)
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT CASE WHEN _level > 1
            THEN jsonb_agg(sub)
            ELSE CASE WHEN count(*) > 0 THEN to_jsonb(count(*) || ' - stopped recursion at max level') END
       END
FROM  (
   SELECT i.*, CASE WHEN _level > 1 THEN f_item_tree(i.item_id, _level - 1) END AS children
   FROM   joins j
   JOIN   items i ON i.item_id = j.child_id
   WHERE  j.item_id = _item_id
   ORDER  BY i.item_id
   ) sub
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ce0d9adcf273b0953189586d78d38848)*

Call with default max levels (7):

```
SELECT jsonb_pretty(jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(sub))) AS tree
FROM  (
   SELECT *, f_item_tree(item_id) AS children
   FROM   items
   WHERE  item_id = 1  -- root item_id HERE
   ) sub;
```

Produces your desired result:

```json
{
    "title": "PARENT",
    "item_id": 1,
    "children": [
        {
            "title": "LEVEL 2",
            "item_id": 2,
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "LEVEL 3.1",
                    "item_id": 3,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "title": "LEVEL 4.1",
                            "item_id": 4
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "LEVEL 4.2",
                            "item_id": 5
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "LEVEL 3.2",
                    "item_id": 6
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Call with just 3 levels:

```
SELECT jsonb_pretty(jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(sub))) AS tree
FROM  (
   SELECT *, f_item_tree(item_id, 3) AS children  -- max level HERE
   FROM   items
   WHERE  item_id = 1  -- root item_id HERE
   ) sub;
```

Note the special output when the recursion is stopped prematurely:

```json
{
    "title": "PARENT",
    "item_id": 1,
    "children": [
        {
            "title": "LEVEL 2",
            "item_id": 2,
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "LEVEL 3.1",
                    "item_id": 3,
                    "children": "2 - stopped recursion at max level"
                },
                {
                    "title": "LEVEL 3.2",
                    "item_id": 6
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The outer `jsonb_pretty()` is optional, of course.

You can wrap outer call into another function or cram it into the same, possibly with PL/pgSQL and switch with `IF`. That's a matter of taste and style. I kept it simple here.

This is *actual* recursion, while [rCTE really just *iterate*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#id-1.5.6.12.5.4). You need to understand the concept to understand the function: it calls itself. Decrementing the maximum `_level` with every call is what eventually terminates recursion.

I built in special behavior for the last recursion level: in case the  max level cuts off more children, the function inserts a count and a hint.

The (optional!) call with [`jsonb_strip_nulls()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) ...

> Deletes all object fields that have null values from the given JSON value, recursively.

Removes empty children fields (with `NULL` value). If there can be additional fields with NULL values you want to keep, consider [`jsonb_set_lax()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) in the function instead, like used below with the pure SQL solution.

Ideally, you have an **index on `joins(item_id, child_id)`** - or a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(item_id, child_id)` which comes with that index implicitly.

Related:

- [For each category, find the count of foreign-key items in all child categories using a PostgreSQL Recursive CTE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121765/for-each-category-find-the-count-of-foreign-key-items-in-all-child-categories-u/121795#121795)

#### Plain SQL

While there is **only a hand full of levels**, you could also spell out a cascade of subqueries or non-recursive CTEs with aggregation.

The query gets rather verbose, but performance should still be good when compared to your original. Due in no small part to the fact that I reverted the initial approach to the query. Since you are interested in a given root ID, it should be **much more efficient** to start at the root instead of the leaves - sticking to the *tree* as metaphor. This way, we only ever select rows that are part of the tree.

The way you had it, all rows of the whole table(s) are being processed, only to filter the one tree stemming from your given root in the end. That's a lot of wasted effort.

Also, I join to `items` once after having selected all relevant nodes, not every time in the recursive term like you had it.

After selecting all nodes of the tree, the aggregation needs to be top-down again, from leaves to the root, since each lower level integrates the aggregated array from the next higher level.

Query for a **maximum of 4 levels** to cover your test data:

```
WITH RECURSIVE path AS (
   SELECT ARRAY[item_id, child_id] AS path, child_id AS item_id, 2 AS lvl
   FROM   joins
   WHERE  item_id = 1  -- root item_id HERE
   
   UNION ALL
   SELECT p.path || j.child_id, j.child_id, p.lvl + 1
   FROM   path  p
   JOIN   joins j ON j.item_id = p.item_id
   WHERE  p.lvl < 7  -- HARD limit
   )
, tree AS (
   SELECT p.*, to_jsonb(i) AS item
   FROM   path p
   JOIN   items i USING (item_id)
   ORDER  BY lvl, item_id
   )
, lvl4 AS (  -- leaf!
   SELECT path[3] AS item_id, jsonb_agg(item) AS children
   FROM   tree
   WHERE  lvl = 4
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
,  lvl3 AS (
   SELECT path[2] AS item_id
        , jsonb_agg(jsonb_set_lax(item, '{children}', children, true, 'return_target')) AS children
   FROM   tree t
   LEFT   JOIN lvl4 USING (item_id)
   WHERE  lvl = 3
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
,  lvl2 AS ( -- stem!
   SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set_lax(item, '{children}', children, true, 'return_target')) AS children
   FROM   tree t
   LEFT   JOIN lvl3 USING (item_id)
   WHERE  lvl = 2
   )
SELECT i.item_id
     , jsonb_pretty(jsonb_set_lax(to_jsonb(i), '{children}', children, true, 'return_target')) AS tree
FROM   items i
LEFT   JOIN lvl2 ON true
WHERE  item_id = 1;  -- root item_id HERE
```

Produces your desired result. Works for fewer levels, too. Or (unlike your original) even a bare root item without any children at all.

It should be obvious how to extend the query to allow more levels. I added a version for **7 levels** to accommodate your `WHERE level < 7` to the fiddle, just in case:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8f78f6d3a75bf3be9ffe268de420f92e)*

Comment: I tried to find a universal SQL-only answer but couldn't come up with one, as I would always end up with the need to outer-join the anchor and Postgres wouldn't let me. Shame, but what can you do.

Comment: Not sure which is faster. The recursive function is more elegant, with less initial overhead, and works for any number of levels. But if the tree forks a lot, the plain SQL version may scale better. Would be interested in some performance test results if you have a big table. (Either should be much faster than your original.)