# Convert PostgreSQL table to structured JSON output

Tags: postgresql, json

I have been having a horrible time dumping this example output into a neatly structured JSON output.

Here is some example data

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE isuck (path text[], city text);
INSERT INTO isuck(path, city)
VALUES
        (ARRAY['Planet Earth','North America','United States','Eastern','New York'],'New York City'),
        (ARRAY['United States','Eastern','New York'],'Manhattan'),
        (ARRAY['United States','Central','Missouri'],'St Louis'),
        (ARRAY['United States','Central','Missouri'],'Wenztville'),
        (ARRAY['United States','Central','Missouri'],'Kansas City'),
        (ARRAY['United States','Central','Illinois'],'Chicaco'),
        (ARRAY['United States','Central','Texas'],'Houston'),
        (ARRAY['Mexico','Jalisco'],'Puerto Vallarta'),
        (ARRAY['Mexico','Jalisco'],'Guadalajara'),
        (ARRAY['Mexico','Baja California'],'Tijuana');
```

I would like to be able to dump this output to JSON in the following format.

```json
{
  "United States": {
    "Eastern": {
      "New York": [
        "New York City",
        "Manhattan"
      ]
    },
    "Central": {
      "Missouri": [
        "St Louis",
        "Wentzville",
        "Kansas City"
      ],
      "Illinois": [
        "Chicago"
      ],
      "Texas": [
        "Houston",
        "Dallas",
        "San Antonio"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Mexico": {
    "Jalisco": [
      "Puerto Vallarta",
      "Guadalajara"
    ],
    "Baja California Sur": [
      "Cabo San Lucas"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is where I have gotten to.

```sql
SELECT   jsonb_build_object(path[1], jsonb_build_object(path[2], jsonb_build_object(path[3], jsonb_agg(city))))
FROM     isuck
GROUP BY path[1],
         path[2],
         path[3]
```

But this fails with the error

> argument 1: key must not be null

I know it is because cities in Mexico are only 2 levels deep whereas cities in the US are 3 levels deep.

Thanks so much for helping steer me in the right direction!

@Erwin,

This is brilliant! One thing is that in my example table, it had a max of 3 levels deep, whereas my real data actually has up to 5. I added two additional sections and it appears to work well but I fear that it might now be the most efficient?

```sql
   SELECT path1, jsonb_object_agg(path2, val) AS val FROM (
   SELECT path1, path2, jsonb_object_agg(path3, val) AS val FROM (
     SELECT path[1] AS path1, path[2] AS path2, path[3] AS path3, jsonb_object_agg(path[4], val) AS val
     FROM   cte
     WHERE  i = 4
     GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3
   ) four_1
    GROUP BY 1, 2
   ) four_2
    GROUP BY 1

   UNION ALL    
   SELECT path1, jsonb_object_agg(path2, val) AS val FROM (
     SELECT path[1] AS path1, path[2] AS path2, jsonb_object_agg(path[3], val) AS val
     FROM   cte
     WHERE  i = 3
     GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ) three_1
    GROUP BY 1

   UNION ALL
```

Comment: May be you can use `coalesce` to handle nulls? Something like `coalesce(path[3],path[2])` instead of just `path[3]`.

Comment: Please tag your PostgreSQL version. 1-Can you modify actual data? 2-Are you trying to get a single row with all the json text?

Comment: I assume the result should just read `"Texas": ["Houston"]`. "Dallas" and "San Antonio" are not in the table.

Answer (score 2):

For the three levels you show in your sample data:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT path[0:i-1] AS path, i-1 AS i, json_object_agg(path[i], cities) AS val
   FROM  (
      SELECT path, cardinality(path) AS i, json_agg(city) AS cities
      FROM   isuck
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   )
SELECT json_object_agg(key, val) AS result
FROM  (
   SELECT path[1] AS key, json_object_agg(path[2], val) AS val
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  i = 2
   GROUP  BY 1

   UNION ALL
   SELECT path[1], val
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  i = 1
   ) sub;
```

Produces the desired result.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8cb8c4a9885071f79e405a7fb07bdd58)* - with prettified jsonb

For details on the used JSON functions read the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html).

Related:

- [Greater than or equal to ALL() and equal to MAX() speed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63184287/939860)
- [How to turn a set of flat trees into a single tree with multiple leaves?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/292572/how-to-turn-a-set-of-flat-trees-into-a-single-tree-with-multiple-leaves/294044#294044)